# Set number of mappers and reducers manually in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have application where it runs multiple map and reduce jobs, I have multiple clients where there data size are different,  I want to fetch number of map assigned for each job  and manually set number of reducers ,

There is one more senario where there is 0 mappers and framework is assigning 1000 reducers which of no use

How can I handle such scenario or is there any way where we can handle programmatically.

Comment: You cannot assign mappers only reducers. And that's been answered many times elsewhere, so what have you tried?

Comment: @cricket_007 Currently, I am hard coding reducers as 500, but for my few clients I don't really need 500 reducers, how can I handle this situation?

Comment: Try an if statement? I don't know what situations you mean

Comment: Any examples or reference with if statement?

Comment: Again, I don't know what you're trying to do or when. It's just an if statement in Java around whatever code you have to set the reducer count.

Comment: The right number of reduces seems to be 0.95 or 1.75 multiplied by ( < no. of nodes > * < no. of maximum containers per node > ). 
On the other hand, I do not really understand when you say that there is 0 mappers, really?